# How many nodes have to confirm a transaction for it to go to a mempool? Or is it somehow based on hashing power?

Tags: transactions

I am trying to understand chronologically what happens to a transaction from the second it is sent to the moment it is added to a block.

Answer (score 1):

None. The mempool is composed by *unconfirmed* transactions.

If you send a valid transaction to other nodes, the first node that receives can be a miner, then it puts on his/her mempool. Or it can send it to other nodes unit it eventually reaches a miner. There's no limit for how many nodes relay it.

Comment: My semantics were off. I should have said validate a transaction instead of confirm a transaction. So let's say there is a network off 100 nodes. A transaction propagates through the network and the 51st node says that it is a validate transaction. Would you argue that a network has reached a consensus that the transaction is indeed valid. Also, I didn't realize that each node has its own mempool thank you for teaching me that!

Comment: The network only 'reach a consensus' by mining, not relaying an validating transactions. That's what's mining for.